# Transition Probability matrix for on/off swtiches

Tags: matrices

Lets say we have $5$ gates. On state is designated by 1 and off state is designated by $0$.

Then, $\{ W_k^i, k =0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is a discrete parameter Markov chains for each gate $i, \{ i = 1,2,3,4,5\}$ with state space $\{0, 1\}$, and its one-step state transition probabilities are:$ a_0, a_1,a_2,a_3$

Now we define $V_k, \{ k =0,1,2,\ldots\}$, where,$V_k = \sum_{i=0}^{5}  W_k^i$. $V_k, \{ k =0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is also a markov chain with state space $\{ 0,1,2,\ldots,5\}$.

How to calculate one-step state probability transition matrix for $V_k$? I know I can use geometric distribution here as: for $0$ gate 'on' $P_{00} = p^5$ and so on. but I can understand how to use that. Any hint is highly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see one **example state transition**, say, $3 \rightarrow 2$. That is, let's see  the following conditional probability:

$$P_{3,2}=P(V_n=2\mid V_{n-1}=3)=3p_{1,0}p_{1,1}^2p_{0,0}^2+3p_{1,0}^2p_{1,1}p_{0,1}p_{0,0}+p_{1,0}^3p_{0,1}^2.$$

**Explanation:**

Out of the three $1$'s

- **either** one $1$ has changed to $0$, two $1$'s have remained $1$'s, and the two $0$'s have remained $0$'s. (There are three different ways to select the $1$ that changes to $0$.)
- **or** two $1$'s have changed to $0$'s, one $1$ has remained $1$, one $0$ has changed to $1$, and one $0$ has remained $0$. (There are three different ways to select the two $1$'s that change to $0$'s.)
- **or** all the three $1$'s have changed to $0$'s and both of the $0$'s have changed to $1$'s. (There is only one way to select all the $1$'s to change.)

Hopefully all the $36$ state transition probabilities can be calculated based on a similar argumentation.

Comment: thank u so much! I will try this now and will post the final result. thanks again!

Comment: This is an extension of the previous question. I have the equation: 
$$Q_k = (Q_{k-1} - 1) + V_k$$
$Q_k$ is the queue length at time instant $k$, $V_k$ is the number of arrivals. At every time instant one customer is processed. Now if the queue length at $k= 2$ is $Q_2 = 3$. So at the next time instant the queue length would be $Q_3 = 2 + V_3$.

Here $V_k$ is already described in the question. 
Although I know the answer that $Q_k$ is not a DPMC but I cant figure it out why. How can I mathematically see/derive this? Any hint is highly appreciated. @zoli. Thank u.